NodeJS http-proxy-middleware
I want to add additional styles and scripts in the  of my application. I'm using Express and http-proxy-middleware to proxy requests and modify the response, but my current approach isn't working as expected.
Here's the code I have tried:
const express = require("express");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const app = express();

// Middleware to intercept and modify the response body
const modifyResponse = (req, res, next) => {
  let originalSend = res.send;

  res.send = function (body) {
    if (typeof body === "string") {
      body = body.replace(
        "</head>",
        '<script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>' +
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/styles.css"></link>' +
        '</head>'
      );
    }
    originalSend.call(this, body);
  };

  next();
};

// Proxy configuration
const proxyConfig = {
  target: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
  changeOrigin: true,
  selfHandleResponse: true, // Allows us to modify the response
  onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
    let body = [];

    proxyRes.on("data", (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
    });

    proxyRes.on("end", () => {
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

      if (
        proxyRes.headers["content-type"] &&
        proxyRes.headers["content-type"].includes("text/html")
      ) {
        body = body.replace(
          "</head>",
          '<script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>' +
          '<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/styles.css"></link>' +
          '</head>'
        );
      }

      res.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
      res.end(body);
    });
  },
  logLevel: "debug",
};

// Use the proxy middleware with the response modifier
app.use("/", modifyResponse, createProxyMiddleware(proxyConfig));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});



What I am trying to achieve:

I want to inject a  and a  tag into the  of the HTML content served from http://127.0.0.1:5500.
This injection should be done dynamically by intercepting the response from the proxied server, modifying it, and then sending the modified response to the client.

